# NullPointerException de-reference a null object Apex Code trigger

Tags: apex

While looking at other examples , what I understood was the if a certain query/field/method returns null - This error will be thrown

Question - Is there a way to find out which part of the code is causing error ?

Comment: You need to include some code. Moreover, If a field return null, it does not throw this exception. Instead, when a field is returned null and then referenced then this exception is thrown. e.g. `String str = null; str.split(',')'`.

Comment: Debug logs or the error message would be a start

Comment: This error always occurs when referencing the null entity. You can check debug log where you will find the line number throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Queries do *not* throw NullPointerException errors. Ever. But, you must always check the record's fields before you attempt to call a method on them, or they can throw this exception.

You can find out which line caused the error by reading the "stack trace." The stack trace will appear as a sequence of classes and line numbers; the first line on the message shows where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following code:

```
Account a = NULL; 

/*

some other stuff

*/

system.debug(a.Name);
```

When you try to run it, a Null Pointer Exception will be thrown, and the you will get the following message:

> **exceptionMessage:** System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   **exceptionStackTrace:** AnonymousBlock: line 9, column 1

Start with the stack trace. The most proximal cause of the problem is on line 9. Here, when we try to get the `Name` of `a`, it doesn't work because `a` is `NULL`. So we work our way back through the code. In this case, it's very easy to see that `a` is `NULL` because we set it to that value on line 1. Real world examples will be more complex, but the principle is the same. Start with where the error is being thrown and keep working your way backwards.

Usually the solution will be to check for a NULL object and only perform the action if the object is not NULL:

```
if (a != NULL){
    system.debug(a.Name);
}
```

or change the way object is being initialized so that there cannot be a NULL:

```
Account a = new Account();
```